# C# making a list in Messagebox with same string?

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I am working on a file manager, where it will move files based on extensions, and file names. I am currently adding messagebox to tell me which files could not be moved, and I am wanting to have it display the file name in the messagebox, and if there is multiple files I want it to display as a list instead of having seperate pop up per file name.

I have tried string builder and it gave me an error in my foreach saying it cant convert char to string. I also tried string.join but gave me the same results as... messageBox.Show("fdsafjdsla");

Comment: please show us the code you used with the string builder in the foreach loop. with string builder inside the loop you should use the AppendLine method, then after the loop is closed when you pass it to the messsage box show method, call the ToString method.

Comment: Show your code otherwise I can only imagine the downvotes as well as the possibility of this post being `Closed`

Comment: also you are not using the string.Join properly.. show your code

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use this

```
Stringbuilder sBuilder = new Stringbuilder();

Foreach(your loop)
{
     sBuilder.Append("the value you want to append" +  Environment.NewLine);
} 

MessageBox.Show(sBuilder.ToString());
```

**Note**
Environment.NewLine -->gives you a new row

If you need **ONLY** filename from a filepath use like this

```
  string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext";
  string result;
  result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
```

**It will output**

myfile.ext

Comment: Ok, I realized I had to make new string names, I was trying to do ones that were already declared. also slight problem it gives me the directory too, I just want the file names.

Comment: Thank you, Care Palsson, Worked perfectly.